# Capture Errors and Errored fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a SettingsController which allows the users to change the
passwords. I am expecting Devise to apply the same validation rules
which are applied for passwords elsewhere.
In my settings controller, I have the following code :

```
    @user.password = new_pwd
    @user.password_confirmation = new_cnf_pwd
    if @user.save
       format.html { redirect_to settings_home_url }
       format.js
   else
       flash[:error] = "Settings cant be saved"
       format.html { redirect_to settings_home_url }
       format.js
    end
```

On the SettingsPage, I have :

```
<%= flash[:error] %>
<%= flash[:warning] %>
<%= flash[:alert] %>
```

In the form, now the flash[:error] which I have set in the
SettingsController is displayed fine. But I want to also display the
Devise default errors like "Passwords do not match" on the form.
Also, I want to flag the errored fields.
Is there a way to do this from a non-devise controller like the one I
have ?
Thanks...
Ved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any validation errors for the model will be available in `@user.errors`, not `flash`.

The [Rails Guides: Displaying Validation Errors in the View](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-the-view) documentation shows you how to then print them out in your view.